# array index out of bounds exception while check condition

Tags: java, android, arrays

i started making a game that named GO at android (traditional japanese game).
refferer : [GO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_%28game%29)

and i want to make a condition in each player gets a turn, so when the player get turn, the condition goes to see the position of the stone, if the stone position that placed it possible to obtain liberty, then run the conditions, otherwise not. here is the coding :

```
public void checkCondition(int position, View v){

    final ImageButton[] arrPlayer1 = { //Board
            g1  ,g2,  g3,  g4,  g5,  g6,  g7,  g8,  g9, 
            g10, g11, g12, g13, g14, g15, g16, g17, g18, 
            g19, g20, g21, g22, g23, g24, g25, g26, g27, 
            g28, g29, g30, g31, g32, g33, g34, g35, g36, 
            g37, g38, g39, g40, g41, g42, g43, g44, g45, 
            g46, g47, g48, g49, g50, g51, g52, g53, g54, 
            g55, g56, g57, g58, g59, g60, g61, g62, g63, 
            g64, g65, g66, g67, g68, g69, g70, g71, g72, 
            g73, g74, g75, g76, g77, g78, g79, g80, g81};

    int posT = position - 9; //Top Position
    int posD = position + 9;  //Down Position
    int posL = position - 1; //Left Position
    int posR = position + 1; //Right Position

    ImageView BlackStone = (ImageView) findViewById(R.drawable.BlackStone);

    if(v == arrPlayer1[position] && arrPlayer1[posT] != null){
        if(arrPlayer1[posT] == BlackStone){
            if(v == arrPlayer1[position] && arrPlayer1[posD] != null){
                if(arrPlayer1[posD] == BlackStone){
                    if(v == arrPlayer1[position] && arrPlayer1[posR] != null){
                        if(arrPlayer1[posR] == BlackStone){
                            if(v == arrPlayer1[position] && arrPlayer1[posL] != null){
                                if(arrPlayer1[posL] == BlackStone){
                                    ChangeTurn(v);
                                }else{
                                    CheckLiberty(position, v);
                                }
                            }
                        }else{
                            CheckLiberty(position, v);
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    CheckLiberty(position, v);
                }
            }
        }else{
            CheckLiberty(position, v);
        }
    }

}
```

My logic is, I make a dynamic condition in this coding so wherever the player went turn, it would see the condition of the stone, ex : if player placed stone at G20, so the logic will see in G11, G19, G21, G29 or etc interconnected stone.

```
int posT = position - 9; //Top Position
int posD = position + 9;  //Down Position
int posL = position - 1; //Left Position
int posR = position + 1; //Right Position
```

but it still error and the logcat give me error array out of bounds exception at the method (CheckCondition). so, what should I do ? any help is appreciated

Comment: Random note: You should not have numbers like 9 randomly in your code.  You the `length` parameter for your array instead.

Comment: That is a total monster of an `if` statement.  I sense many bugs in this...

Comment: What is the value of position, what if there is a situation where position -+ 9 is out of the array index.

Answer (score 2):

First Change:

`ImageView BlackStone = (ImageView) findViewById(R.drawable.BlackStone);`

To

`ImageView BlackStone = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IdOfImageview);`

You need to find view of any component by its `Id` not its `background` as you are using `findViewById`.